# How to search in a list of results on elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

How to search in a list like an indexed array and I'm new on Elasticsearch please let me know what is the name of some concepts. I don't know which concept is true, for example: Is it better to say array, object, properties, or list in my question?

This is my result in Kibana when I run `GET car/_doc/4`

```
{
    "_index" : "car",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "4",
    "_version" : 2,
    "_seq_no" : 7,
    "_primary_term" : 1,
    "found" : true,
    "_source" : {
      "id" : 4,
      "user_id" : 7,
      "ads" : {
        "0" : {
          "id" : 1,
          "priority" : 1,
          "city_id" : 83,
          "model_id" : 13
        },
        "2" : {
            "id" : 4,
            "priority" : 2,
            "city_id" : 54,
            "model_id" : 23
        }  
      },
      "status" : 1
    }
  }
```

And this is my result for `GET car/_doc/15`

```
{
    "_index" : "car",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "15",
    "_version" : 2,
    "_seq_no" : 27,
    "_primary_term" : 1,
    "found" : true,
    "_source" : {
      "id" : 15,
      "user_id" : 24,
      "ads" : [
        {
          "id" : 5,
          "priority" : 4,
          "city_id" : 42,
          "model_id" : 11
        }
      ],
      "status" : 1
    }
  }
```

As you see, I have 2 types of ads. My question is how to search When `status is 1` and (`ads.city_id = 83 OR ads.0.city_id = 83`)

I can use:

```
GET car/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "ads.city.slug": ["LA"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work for the other type of ads and I need to use something like this:

```
GET car/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "ads.2.city.slug": ["NewYork"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How to write a query without writing an index of ads (`2`)?

Comment: normalization of data is important in Elasticsearch. I will suggest you to normaliz your data before indexing to the elasticsearch. please make sure that both ads have same type of data in elasticsearch so you should get by using only one type of query.
Also, here elasticsearch will be consider "0" or "2" as key and not as index of ads. first is type of array and second example is type of object.

Comment: @SagarPatel Your comment was my answer. it's correct.

Answer (score 2):

As SagarPatel suggested in comment, do normalize the `ads` field as an array of objects (like it is for doc with `id: 15` in your example). After that create an index with defined static mapping like this:

```
PUT /your-index-name
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "ads": {
        "type": "nested" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(BTW it is advisable to define static mappings for other fields as well)

Nested type will index `ads` objects as separate inner documents. See [elastic docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html)

After adding documents to the created index you can run queries as follows:

```
GET /your-index-name/_search
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "ads",
                    "query": {
                        "term": {
                            "ads.city_id": {
                                "value": 83
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "ads",
                    "query": {
                        "term": {
                            "ads.city_id": {
                                "value": 94
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "minimum_should_match" : 1 // OR clause
    }
}
```